# C# Problems with updating a Windows Service and access denied

Tags: c#, service

I've been banging my head on this problem for a while, so now I come to you for help.

The Setup: I have two services; Main and Updater. Both are set to run automatic and uses Local System. They are each responsible for keeping the other up to date by timers - this is done by comparing the assembly version with a version received from an API. If there's a mismatch a new version is downloaded.

Both services work. The update functionality also mostly works. When there's a version mismatch the service is properly updated, installed and runs - however, if there continue to be a mismatch I get a Access denied error on the service's exe file on the second and every following run.

Here is my comparer:

```
public void CompareVersions()
    {
        Log("------------------------------------");
        Log(applicationPath);

        var api = new API();
        var version = api.GetVersion().Result;

        if (File.Exists(applicationPath))
        {
            //Get the assembly info of the service.
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(applicationPath));
            var assemblyVersion = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
            var assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name.ToString();
            Log($"Current Version is \t{assemblyVersion}");
            //Update the service if there is a version mismatch.

            if (assemblyName.Equals(careName))
            {
                Log($"Server version is \t{version.CareService}");
                if (!assemblyVersion.Equals(version.CareService))
                {
                    Update();
                }
            }
            if (assemblyName.Equals(updateName))
            {
                Log($"Server version is \t{version.UpdateService}");
                if (!assemblyVersion.Equals(version.UpdateService))
                {
                    Update();
                }
            }

            //Install the service if it doesn't exist, start it if it does.
            //An auto starter has been added to each Service's ProjectInstaller constructor.
            //Service should start on install thanks to this. 
            if (!DoesServiceExist())
            {
                InstallService(applicationPath);
            }
            else
            {
                StartService();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DownloadAndExtractZip();
            InstallService(applicationPath);
        }
    }
```

And the Update():

```
private void Update()
{
    StopAndUninstallService();
    DownloadAndExtractZip();
    InstallService(applicationPath);
}
```

The StopAndUninstall:

```
private void StopAndUninstallService()
    {
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
        var serviceController = new ServiceController
        {
            ServiceName = serviceName
        };

        if (DoesServiceExist())
        {
            if (IsServiceRunning())
            {
                Log($"Attempting to stop service {serviceName}");
                serviceController.Stop();
                serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
                if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                    Log($"{serviceName} has been stopped");
                else
                    Log($"**Could not stop {serviceName}");
            }
            try
            {
                var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller
                {
                    Context = new InstallContext(),
                    ServiceName = serviceName
                };
                serviceInstaller.Uninstall(null);

                if (!DoesServiceExist())
                    Log($"{serviceName} has been uninstalled");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log($"**Uninstall error** {ex.Message}");
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

So far these things work as they should - the service is stopped and removed before attempting next step - the download.

```
private void DownloadAndExtractZip()
    {
        var ftpURL = "ftp.adress.com";
        var ftpFile = ftpURL + fileName + ".zip";

        var downloadedFile = $@"{installationFolder}\{serviceName}\{fileName}.zip";
        var downloadPath = $@"{installationFolder}\{serviceName}";

        try
        {
            Log("Starting download");
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpFile);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (Directory.Exists(downloadPath))
                Directory.Delete(downloadPath, true);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadPath);

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(downloadedFile))
            {
                responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            Log($"Download status, status {response.StatusDescription}");
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log($"**Download Error** {ex.Message}");
        }

        try
        {
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(downloadedFile, downloadPath);
            Log("File Extracted!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log($"**Extraction Error** {ex.Message}");
        }

    }
```

The access denied error comes when I try to delete the directory, specifically I get an UnauthorizedAccessException.

Here's a quick tester I wrote to dive into the issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            System.Console.WriteLine("Creating object");
            var updater = new Updater("ServiceName", "FileName");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Comparing");

            updater.CompareVersions();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
```

And lastly my constructor:

```
public Updater(string serviceName, string fileName)
    {
        var settings = new Settings();
        installationFolder = settings.InstallationFolder;

        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        applicationPath = $@"{installationFolder}\{serviceName}\{fileName}.exe";
    }
```

here's a log extract that shows the timeline:

```
18/01/2022 14.18.44 ------------------------------------
18/01/2022 14.18.44 C:\path\filename.exe
18/01/2022 14.18.44 Current Version is  1.0.0.6
18/01/2022 14.18.44 Server version is   1.0.0.7
18/01/2022 14.18.49 Starting download
18/01/2022 14.18.49 Download status, status 226 Successfully transferred "/latest/filename.zip"

18/01/2022 14.18.50 File Extracted!
18/01/2022 14.18.55 ServiceName has been installed
18/01/2022 14.18.55 ServiceName is already running
18/01/2022 14.19.05 ------------------------------------
18/01/2022 14.19.05 C:\path\filename.exe
18/01/2022 14.19.05 Current Version is  1.0.0.6
18/01/2022 14.19.05 Server version is   1.0.0.7
18/01/2022 14.19.05 Attempting to stop service ServiceName
18/01/2022 14.19.05 ServiceName has been stopped
18/01/2022 14.19.10 ServiceName has been uninstalled
18/01/2022 14.19.15 Starting download
18/01/2022 14.19.15 **Download Error** Access to the path 'filename.exe' is denied.
18/01/2022 14.19.15 **Extraction Error** Could not find file 'C:\path\filename.zip'.
18/01/2022 14.19.27 **Install error** The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
18/01/2022 14.19.33 **Install error** The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
```

Any idea what's going on?